# Error FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I try to do [Java File Upload Tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFileUpload) and i got [this trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18121353/how-to-upload-copy-move-file-in-play-framework-with-java).

My file was uploaded into `tmp` folder of `File System` in `Linux` like this :

```
/tmp/multipartBody7066610990481359884asTemporaryFile
```

I have no ideal to change path of upload file so i copy it into `/myproject/public/upload/` by `Java code`. After that i got this error:

```
[FileNotFoundException: /home/thangnk/demo/public/upload (Is a directory)]
```

I doubled check this error and i'm sure that `upload` folder had been created. So anyone can tell me how to fix it ?.

Here is my code:

---Application.java

```
public class Application extends Controller {

  public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
  }

public static Result upload() throws IOException {
          MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
          FilePart picture = body.getFile("picture");
          if (picture != null) {
            String fileName = picture.getFilename();
            String contentType = picture.getContentType(); 
            File file = picture.getFile();

            String orig = file.getAbsolutePath();
            String dest = "/home/thangnk/demo/public/upload/";

    //Copy file     
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(orig);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
               out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();

            return ok("File uploaded");
          } else {
            flash("error", "Missing file");
            return redirect(routes.Application.index());    
          }
        }
}
```

One more question. What's the easiest way to upload images in Play Framework 2.0 ?

Thanks for reading!!!

Comment: Try String dest = "/home/thangnk/demo/public/upload/fileName"

Comment: Thank ihsan.It worked but all file which i uploaded will have same name. Any ideal for this trouble ?

Comment: fileName is get from String fileName = picture.getFilename();
so as the name of picture's fileName changes, our fileName variable will change also.

Comment: Thank ihsan :) worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that `/home/thangnk/demo/public/upload` *is* a directory, but you're trying to name your destination file that. You need to add a file name to the end of your `dest` string, perhaps with `dest + file.getName()`. Make sure you've thought about how to handle if someone tries to upload a file with the same name as one that already exists.